# Sql Server - Return all records after the last instance of a trigger value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below example, the query needs to return all records after, and including, the last `'bar'` (sorted by Id).  So it would return the last three records.

If `'bar'` doesn't exist, the query needs to return all records.

```
Id     Trigger  
1      foo      
2      foo     
3      **bar**      
4      foo      
5      **bar**      
6      foo  
7      foo
```

Trying to figure out an elegant solutions without (or minimal) subqueries, if-thens, variables...

Comment: Aside: If performance is a concern then an index on `Trigger asc, Id desc` may be of value. The first entry should be the starting point for your results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to compute the maximum id of rows that contain `'bar`'. When the subquery returns no rows, `COLAESCE` can be used to provide a default value of `0`.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.id >= COALESCE(
    (SELECT max(id) from mytable where trigger = 'bar'),
    0
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6943948f1b28855427b500dfd35cada7)*

```
WITH mytable as (
    SELECT 1 id, 'a' trig
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'foo'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'bar'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'zoo'
)
SELECT id
FROM mytable t
WHERE id >= COALESCE(
    (SELECT max(id) from mytable where trig = 'bar'),
    0
)
GO
```

```
 | id |
 | -: |
 |  3 |
 |  4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery that uses conditional aggregation to get the maximum ID where the value is equal to 'bar' or the minimum ID if there was no 'bar'.

```
SELECT *
       FROM [elbat] t1
       WHERE t1.[id] >= (SELECT coalesce(max(CASE t2.[trigger]
                                               WHEN 'bar' THEN
                                                 t2.[id]
                                             END),
                                         min(t2.[id]))
                                FROM [elbat] t2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d2b69d6cb12e972001804ca31d0313d3)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want all rows where there is not a row with a greater `'bar'` value.  I think the most elegant way to express this is:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.trigger = 'bar' and t2.id > t.id
                 );
```

Another method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when trigger = 'bar' then id end) over () as max_bar_id
      from t
     )
where max_bar_id is null or
      id >= max_bar_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one using Windowed Aggregates, mainly usefull if the base data is the result of complex query (because there's only one access to it) or you need to assign multiple foo/bar groups:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT *
     -- cumulative count, assigns 0 to the first group of foo/bar rows
     ,Count(CASE WHEN [trigger] = 'bar' THEN 1 end) -- only count 'bar'
      Over (ORDER BY id DESC -- highest id first
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS flag
   FROM tab
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE flag = 0 -- first group
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1ccc15e5d6faff29321d0cea2d9e2f0f)